# Convert object and push in Array in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have service and method `getCategory()` for get category from server. 
Method is :

```
getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]> (this.productUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
        );
}
```

In my component I want store data in list `categoryList: CategoryModel[];`
 with method

```
getCategory(): void {
        this.dataStorageServiceService.getCategory()
            .subscribe(
                (cateogrys: CategoryModel[]) => {
                    this.categoryList = cateogrys;
                    console.log(this.categoryList)
                }
            }
```

And in output`categoryList` [image] is Object, and I can not render on the template.

Comment: Are you using Firebase?

Comment: Yes. I using Firebase.

Comment: `Object.values`?

Comment: With firebase you will get objects and not arrays. for more info: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 4):

> Since you are getting the object instead of an Array. You have two options, either you convert your Object to Array or use `KeyValuePipe` in the html template -

```
 <div *ngFor="let category of categoryList | keyvalue">
      {{category.key}}:{{category.value}}
  </div>
```

For more info visit - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610-beta1-2018-06-13

Answer (score 2):

With firebase you will get objects and not arrays. for more info: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

So one solution is to "convert" the object to an array when you fetch it in your service:

```
return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]> (this.productUrl)
  .pipe(
    map(products => {
      return Object.values(products);

      // OR

      return Object.keys(products).map((keyName) => {
        return {id: keyName, product: products[keyName]};
      });
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
  );
```

Comment: `Object.values(products);` is supper cleaner than `KeyValuePipe`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this ,

```
categoryList : CategoryModel[] = [];
```

And then you can push the user object and make as a array,

```
this.categoryList .push(<<the data you want to push>>);
```